# rsync hangs at certain point

Tags: rsync

I'm running backup with simple rsync command:

`sudo rsync -avr --delete --max-size=4G '/absolute-path/source' '/absolute-path/target'`

The trouble is, sync always stop at certain point - one small txt file and it won't go on any further.

- Source file-system: `ntfs`
- Target file-system: `vfat` (external HDD)
- Drive have enough space left

No log info. Adding `-vvv` didn't helped me to learn what happened. It just freezes, external drive still mounted and running.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, though I don't know what exactly caused and solved it. The problem seems to be that the permissions on the backup drive were mucked up, so after deleting the entire directory where the file is in on the backup drive and trying again worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it different way - converted external drive to NTFS via windows tool `convert.ext`:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456984.aspx

No troubles after that.